# VBA - Document Not Saving?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, office-automation

Code below. The imported document is not being saved as "document_test.docx". I'm not getting any errors, it's as if the script is running successfully, but I don't see any file!

```
Public Sub testing_1()
    
    Dim filePathRoot As String
    filePathRoot = ThisWorkbook.Path
    
    Dim narApplication As Word.Application
    Dim narDocument As Word.document
    Set narApplication = CreateObject("word.application")
    Set narDocument = narApplication.Documents.Open(filePathRoot & "/document_template.docx")
    
    Dim TITLE As String
    Dim WORTH As String
    Dim NOTWORTH As String
    Dim PAYOFF As String
    
    Dim myRange As Word.range
    Dim myFind As Word.Find
    
    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    
    TITLE = range("B1").Value
    Set myRange = narDocument.Content
    Set myFind = myRange.Find
    With myFind
        .Text = "__TITLE__"
        searchResult = .Execute
    End With
    narDocument.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=myRange, Address:=filePathRoot & "/model.xlsx", SubAddress:="Sheet1!B1", TextToDisplay:=TITLE
    
    
    narDocument.SaveAs2 Filename:=filePathRoot & "/document_test.docx"
    
    ' Cleanup
    narDocument.Close False
    narApplication.Quit False
    Set narApplication = Nothing
    Set narDocument = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Try adding `narApplication.Visible = True` so you can see if there's any problem on the Word side of things.  You won't see any pop-ups if the application is not visible.

Comment: Did you try to run the code under the debugger? Do you get any errors there?

Comment: Are you saving it to a OneDrive ? If not you shouldn't you be using `"\"  instead of "/" in file paths ?